# DataTable Validator

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, validation

How can I define a `validator` for a `DataTable`? For example to force it at least have 1 **row** to **submit**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following (not tested):

Bind your h:dataTable to a UIComponent in the backing bean:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.myList}" var="item" id="myId" binding="#{myBean.myTable}">
```

In your backing bean define a `javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable myTable`

In the action method for the submit button:

```
if (myTable.getRowCount() < 1) {
   FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Your short message", "Your detailed message); 
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMsg);
   return null; // reload view
}
```

Comment: thanks but i'm looking for something in the facelet not in the bean! :)

Comment: Then you could call a javascript/jQuery method from your submit button that counts the number of table rows.

Comment: You mean that there is no way by adding a validator tag or something like that?

Comment: I understood your comment that you want to do it on the client side without involving the server. As far as I know, a validator works on the server side. But I think in fact you want to check row count without extra coding in a bean i.e. by using a standard validator. I do not know any.

Comment: The point is that I don't concern that the validation will perform on client side or server side, I just want it to be in the facelet code, not in the bean code. something like the length and required attributes of the <h:inputText>